# Java regex to extract fields with or without quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, quotes, key-value

I am trying to extract key-value pairs from a long string in two basic forms, one with and one without quotes, like

```
... a="First Field" b=SecondField ...
```

using the `Java` regular expression

```
\b(a|b)\s*(?:=)\s*("[^"]*"|[^ ]*)\b
```

However, running the following test code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "a=\"First Field\" b=SecondField";
  String regex = "\\b(a|b)\\s*(?:=)\\s*(\"[^\"]*\"|[^ ]*)\\b";
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " = " + matcher.group(2));
  }
}
```

the output is

```
a = "First
b = SecondField
```

instead of the desired (without quotes)

```
a = First Field
b = SecondField
```

In a more generalized input, like

```
a ="First Field" b=SecondField c3= "Third field value" delta = "" e_value  = five!
```

the output should be (again, without quotes and with varying amounts of white space before and after the `=` sign)

```
a = First Field
b = SecondField
c3 = Third field value
delta = 
e_value = five!
```

Is there a regular expression to cover the above use case (at least the version with the 2 keys), or should one resort to string processing?

Even trickier question: if there is such a regex, is there also any way of keeping the index of the matcher group corresponding to the value constant, so that both the quoted field value and the unquoted field value correspond to the same group index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2

```
(\w+)=(?:")?(.*?(?="?\s+\w+=|(?:"?)$))
```

here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zR7cW9/2)

sample code:

```
String str = "a=\"First Field\" b=SecondField c=\"ThirdField\" d=\"FourthField\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(?:\")?(.*?(?=\"?\\s+\\w+=|(?:\"?)$))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("key : " + m.group(1) + "\tValue : " + m.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
key : a Value : First Field
key : b Value : SecondField
key : c Value : ThirdField
key : d Value : FourthField
```

---

If you are looking for just `a` and `b` keys then just make slight change in the regex pattern.

Replace first `\w+` with `a|b`

```
(a|b)=(?:")?(.*?(?="?\s+\w+=|(?:"?)$))
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zR7cW9/4)

---

#### EDIT

As per edit of the post

simply add `\s` to check for white spaces as well.

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:")?(.*?(?="?\s+\w+\s*=|(?:"?)$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zR7cW9/6)

Comment: @Unihedron this regex pattern also works if there is an space for `Second Field`

Answer (score 8):

You can modify your regex to the following:

```php
/\b(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|([^ ]*)\b)/
```

Notable changes:

- You can use `\w+` in java to capture word characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
- You do not need to wrap `=` in a non-capturing group `(?:=)`.
- The alternation is now wrapped in a non-capturing group.
- The match should only end with a word boundary when not finished by `"`.

Please see the following code:

```java
{
    String input = "a =\"First Field\" b=SecondField c3= \"Third field value\" delta = \"\" e_value  = five!";
    String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(?:\"([^\"]*)\"|([^ ]*)\\b)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " = " +
        (matcher.group(2) == null ? matcher.group(3) : matcher.group(2)));
}
```

View a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vP9wA2/2) and a [code demo](http://ideone.com/I4exwn)!

> Code demo `STDOUT`:
>
> ```
> a = First Field
> b = SecondField
> c3 = Third field value
> delta = 
> e_value = five
> ```

Comment: @Unihedron op wants the  second field must be captured by same group.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Conditionals and Branch Resets does not exist in Java. As unfortunate as it is, my simplest approach (following [user3218114](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3218114/user3218114)['s solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134798#25134798)) would be to use two capturing groups. It's feasible in this case as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your java regex "\b(a|b)\s*(?:=)\s*("[^"]*"|[^ ]*)\b" will produce the output:

```
a = "First
b = SecondField
```

It's due to after'"' is not a \b boundary. therefore, your first name/value pair with quotaiton will never be matched.
You could change it a bit like this:

```
"\b(a|b)\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|([^ ]*))"
```

The whole sample code is listed as below:

```
String input = "a=\"First Field\" b=SecondField";
String regex = "\\b(a|b)\\s*=\\s*(?:\"([^\"]*)\"|([^ ]*))";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    if(matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " = " + matcher.group(2));
    }else {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " = " + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

The output is like:

```
a = First Field
b = SecondField
```

Meanwhile, if your key is not just 'a or b', it's a workd, then you could chang (a|b) to (\w+)

Answer (score 0):

```
    (a|b)\s*(?:=)\s*("[^"]*"|[^ ]*)
```

Tried with this.Works fine.
http://regex101.com/r/zR7cW9/1

Comment: what about long string for ex: `a="First Field" b=SecondField c="ThirdField"`

Comment: @user3218114..... the attempted re was not generic...so i too didnt try that.....