# I have to put a number into an integer, after a specific word

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

My code reads the whole .txt document, and it put the content into a string. In my text document, there's two word(Pos v="1" and Qty v="224"). I have to get those number in different integers. Like int Pos, and int Qty.

I tried to split the string, which contained the text document's content, and I've tried to get the index of the elements, and then to put them into the integers.

```
try {
    String content = new String ( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get(filePath) ) );
    //System.out.println(content);
    String[] datas = content.split("Pos v=\"");
    System.out.println(datas[300]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Valami hiba van a megadott elérési úttal");
}
```

There wasn't any error with it, it was just hard to do it like this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134348/java-regex-to-extract-fields-with-or-without-quotes

Comment: Post the actual contents of the file and expected output.

Comment: I have two different Strings. the first is <Pos v="1"/>, and the second is <Qty v="2.6"/>. I want to get the number out of them, and I want to put the numbers into two different doubles. the first double's name would be pos, and the second double's name would be qty.

Comment: If there's no error in your code you can use `Integer.parseInt()` to create an int out of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest keeping track of each word and once you got your word either `Pos` or `Qty`; extract number from next word which would be `v="1"`(1 can be replaced with any value)

```
 int pos;
 int qty;

 // wordArray is an array formed by splitting string with space delimeter
 for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length - 1; i++){
   // matching whether current word is "Pos" or  "Qty"
   if(wordArray[i].equals("Pos")) {
     // wordArray[i+1] = "v="1""; we are extracting only digit from that word
     pos = Integer.parseInt(wordArray[i+1].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
   } else if(wordArray[i].equals("Qty")) {
     qty = Integer.parseInt(wordArray[i+1].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
   }       
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but how can I edit it, to be able to store doubles too, and not just integers?